# Windows User Folders Called Username.Hostname After Leaving ActiveDirectory Domain/Demoting Server from AD Controller

Tags: windows, active-directory

After demoting a Windows Server 2019 from an ActiveDirectory domain controller to a regular server (which naturally deletes all user accounts except for the Administrator account) I recreated a few user accounts which does create the correct user folder `C:\Users\Username`. Once that user logs in, another folder `C:\Users\Username.Hostname` is created though. (Hostname being the machine's name)

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the folders exist before the user logs in for the first time, Windows will always create a new folder. If they're domain users the folder will be `Username.Domain`, otherwise it will be `Username.Hostname`.

I suggest following these steps:

1. **Backup any necessary files from `C:\Users\Username` and `C:\Users\Username.Hostname`.**
2. Open *System Properties* through:

   1. open the *Run* dialog → `sysdm.cpl`
   2. right click *This PC*/*Computer*/*My Computer* → *Properties*.
   3. press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd> and click *Advanced properties*
3. Go to the *Advanced* tab and click the *Settings…* button under *User Profiles*.
4. Delete the profiles you're having an issue with. If you didn't do this before demoting, they may show up by their ID's instead of the username, so be careful.
5. Open File Explorer and delete **both** the `C:\Users\Username` and `C:\Users\Username.Hostname` folders if they are left behind. This is common for really big profiles.
6. Log the user back in again.
7. Verify that the folders are created correctly and restore the backed up files there.

Comment: This worked perfectly for all the users that hadn't yet logged in after re-creation (and thus had two folders created). The other user accounts I had to fully delete and recreate plus delete their profile as you outlined. For the non-deletable built-in Administrator account, I had to change the ProfileImagePath in the registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList). This might have also been possible for the other accounts.